# Permissions error with logrotate

Tags: raspbian, script, logfiles

I am using a script to monitor a service. I have added said script in `crontab`. `crontab` runs the script every **one minute**.

I have found this script online and it works pretty good, but it writes the logs to `/var/mail/pi` and that file does not rotate.

These are the permissions for `/var/mail` and `/var/mail/pi` :

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail       4096 Oct 15 13:48 mail
-rw-rw---- 1 pi   mail 1425632 Oct 15 13:49 pi
```

In `/etc/logrotate.conf` I have added:

```
/var/mail/pi {
    rotate 7
    daily
    su pi mail
}
```

Running `logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` returns, among other rotating patterns, the following:

```
rotating pattern: /var/mail/pi  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8
error: error switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8: Operation not permitted
error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied
```

Running `sudo logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` returns:

```
rotating pattern: /var/mail/pi  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 8
considering log /var/mail/pi
  Now: 2019-10-15 14:46
  Last rotated at 2019-10-15 14:35
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

Running `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` with or without `sudo` doesn't return any error regarding `/var/mail/pi` but only `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` creates `pi.1` and/or `pi.2` and so on.

I have no idea if the rotating pattern works or not.

Comment: Take the `su pi mail` out.   If the issue is the mode of the files it creates, use an explicit `create` directive to set that, or use `chmod`/`chown` in `postrotate`.

Comment: @goldilocks Why remove `su pi mail` ? I have just checked and it made a new log file today. If I remove it, not even `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` will work. It returns: `error: skipping "/var/mail/pi" because parent directory has insecure permissions`

Comment: @goldilocks `create 666 pi mail` also returns `skipping "/var/mail/pi" because parent directory has insecure permissions`

Comment: @goldilocks Also, how to add `chmod/chown` in `postrotate` if I don't know the name of the file ? It can be pi.1, pi.2, pi.3, pi.4, pi.5, pi.6, pi.7 ...

Comment: You could use an appropriate wild card (`"pi.*"`, make sure it is enclosed in quotes) -- but I was wondering why it did not work as is and just had a closer look at your question: *"I have no idea if the rotating pattern works or not"*.  You need to determine that, because if it works run `sudo` then it should work via system `crontab` (**not** the pi user one); if you need to ask a question, *"How can I tell if logrotate is working or not?"*, do so, but do it on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  The pi is not really relevant here.

Comment: @goldilocks The point is that using `su pi mail` works. I have been testing it for the past 2 days and it works. It created so far pi.1 and pi.2 and each log contains logs with their respective day in which the Raspberry was on. But you said to ditch `su pi mail`. Maybe the question should be "How to TEST if logrotate works ?" . Because that's where `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` comes into play.

Comment: @goldilocks If I couldn't force the rotation with `sudo` I assumed that using `create` won't work.

Comment: @goldilocks I've just booted up the Rapberry and `create` made a new log file, but deleted the yesterday log file.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate): it's a tool designed to run as a `cron` job which will automatically rotate, compress, delete and mail logfiles based on the rules you write in its config file.

Here's a sample config from the man page:

```
/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    weekly
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
```

This means: every week `/var/log/messages` file will be compressed to something like `/var/log/messages.1.gz` and removed, and 5 most recent compressed log files will be kept (the old `messages.1.gz` will be renamed to `messages.2.gz` and so on). After this action, `syslogd` will be told to recreate a new log file.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica if your config file says the logs should be rotated daily, they will be rotated daily regardless of how often you run `logrotate`. Change the current date if you want to test. Also, unless your script uses `logger` or similar, there is no reason to reload `syslogd`. If your script doesn't keep the log file open all the time (which I think is the case), you shouldn't use "postrotate" at all.

Comment: I have edited the question once again. Also, why can't I use @ and your name Dmitry Grigoryev ?

Comment: GFF, I've just noticed that this question started out as something to which this was an answer. Right now it does not make a lot of sense because you subsequently changed the question to something about how to use logrotate.  For future reference, please understand that's not how this site works: We aren't "discussion style" where a thread can morph and twist endlessly.  Part of the idea is to maximize the value to posterity.  Changing a question to invalidate someone's answer messes with that, and is considered seriously inconsiderate...

Comment: ..Chaining a prolonged series of follow-up questions in comments is also generally inappropriate.  It's fine to ask for clarification on a few points, but the crux of both these issues is *when you have a new, distinct question, ask a new, distinct question* (via "Ask Question", not comments).  There is [a tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) that may explain all this better.  WRT using @, it won't work when it is redundant, such as addressing the author of an answer in comments on that answer (because the author is notified regardless).